# Using different line styles instead of colours

Tags: reporting-services, charts, lines

I'm making a SQL Reporting Services report in Visual Studio 2010.  The report requires a line chart on it.

It comes out with different colours for different series groups which is ok.  However, because it maybe printed out on a black and white printer i've been asked to change the lines to use dashes , dots etc. rather than colours.

Is this possible and if so how? I've seen examples in 2005 but the designer is completely different in Visual Studio 2010 and I can't find anything similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can set this conditional line style using the following option:

[image]

Under **Border** -> **Line Style** you need to set the expression, something like:

```
=IIf(Fields!groupingValue.Value = 1, "Solid", "Dashed")
```

You could change this to a `Switch` expression if you need more complicated logic.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you find an answer helpful, please considering upvoting and/or marking it as the accepted answer.